Limits of integration in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$
I've found this question in a past high-school final exam I'm going over for practice:
It is known that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$ Determine whether $u \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_{-\infty}^ue^{-x^2}dx = 1$$ is positive or negative.
Now, this can be answered using the fact that, since $e^{-x^2}$ is an even function, $$\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},$$ and hence $u > 0$ since $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} > 1$.
But what to do if I want to determine the value of $$\int_{-u}^ux^7e^{-x^2}dx?$$

$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is an even function.

@JulioPuerta -- That's only half of the answer, it lacks the hint that $\sqrt{\pi}/2\lt 1$.

@Julio Puerta So $$\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} < 1,$$ and so $u > 0$?

@m-stgt I believe that hint is more than sufficient.

@JulioPuerta -- sure, for you and me, but maybe not for OP.

@JulioPuerta No one here seems to care proving the existence of such a $u$.

@Sam Of course, because that is trivial.

@JulioPuerta Ofcourse it is for us.

$\int_{-u}^ux^7e^{-x^2}dx=0$, as the integral of an odd function over $[-u,u]$. And I don't think this chameleon question should be reopened.

Define the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt$, then $f$ is a continuous and differentiable function over the real line.  Since $f'(x) = e^{-x^2} > 0$, $f$ is monotone and therefore $f$ is invertible in it's range. This implies that such a $u$ exists. Now $u>0$ is positive since $$f(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} < 1 < \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \sqrt{\pi}. $$
Edit: invertibility is not required, all you need is IVT and the fact that $1$ is in the range of the function. Due to monotonicity, invertibility argument was easier to make.

Thank you. It's not really needed for the exercise in my question, but I think I'm lacking the relevant background in analysis to fully understand your comment: why does the invertibility of $f$ guarantee the existence of such a $u$?

@JulioPuerta -- The poor quality of the question shows the limited background of the questioner. Thus help is more appropriate than downvotes me think.

@m-stgt That is not the policy of the site.

@JulioPuerta What do you mean by 'poor quality'? Should I have added assumptions that guarantee that the problem is well-posed? Sorry, I don't have a background in analysis.

The question can be answered in a line. Apart from that, you should have included your attempt and not just show the question.
